# Could you show me Opencart Journal theme excute route?

Tags: opencart-3

Journal 3.1.4
When I visit http://localhost/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=31
And I in catalog\controller\product\product.php , inside public function index(){
want to exit; but I found it didn't run this file, I want to change something is difficult, please tell me the route logic, thank you very much!

Comment: Journal theme is not compliant OC software you should avoid this journal 3 theme.

Comment: Okay, I just wondering the reason, Thanks!